# MQTT events to generate task queues in the RabbitMQ broker

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt

How can I feed all MQTT events into a RabbitMQ broker without processing them?
Is there an automatic way, via configuration, for MQTT events to generate task queues in the RabbitMQ broker?

Comment: What do you mean by "generate task queues"? How many queues do you want to create? How shall they be named and bound to exchanges? How is this related to MQTT events?

Comment: so you want to subscribe to all mqtt events?

Comment: I intend that upon receipt of a publication of an MQTT event a Queue will be generated in the RabbitMq broker automatically. My intention is from MQTT event publications to automatically generate a message in a queue in Broker RabbitMq and then these messages will be consumed by clients in nodejs who will be subscribing to this queue.